# External Portal In Unifi

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I am creating an external portal in unifi AC, where by users will be authenticated then after if they exist they will be allowed to use the internet connection for sometime the problem is after the user has been authenticated i got some codes which allow the user to use the internet but they are not working for me.
so The user is authenticated in the external portal but is not allowed to start 
using internet the codes which should allow a user to start using internet is 
in the function sendAuthentication.

The login.php source codes.

```
<?php session_start(); 
require_once('dbconnect.php');
$username   =   trim($_POST['username']);
$password   =   trim(md5($_POST['pass']));
$query  =   "select * from students where email='".$username."' &&  password='".$password."'";
$result =   mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$row    =   mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($username === $row['email'] && $password === $row['password']){
    //Minutes to authorize, change to suit your needs
     echo '<script language="javascript">';
     echo 'alert("Successfully login")';
     echo '</script>';
     sendAuthorization($_SESSION['id'], (12*60));
     return true;       
     }
      else{

     $_SESSION['error']=TRUE;
     header('location:http://b4w.uhuruone.co.tz/guest/s/default/');

     }


     function sendAuthorization($id, $minutes)
     {
$unifiServer = "https://41.38.13.78:8443";
$unifiUser = "bro4wote";
$unifiPass = "rt@b45w";

// Start Curl for login
$ch = curl_init();
// We are posting data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
// Set up cookies
$cookie_file = "/tmp/unifi_cookie";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
// Allow Self Signed Certs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
// Force SSL3 only
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
// Login to the UniFi controller
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$unifiServer/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "login=login&username=$unifiUser&password=$unifiPass");
// send login command
curl_exec ($ch);

// Send user to authorize and the time allowed
$data = json_encode(array(
    'cmd'=>'authorize-guest',
    'mac'=>$id,
    'minutes'=>$minutes));

// Send the command to the API
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/api/cmd/stamgr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json='.$data);
curl_exec ($ch);

// Logout of the UniFi Controller
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/logout');
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);
}
?>
<p>Connecting to the network...</p>
<script>
//allow time for the authorization to go through
setTimeout("location.href='http://www.Google.com'",6000);
</script>
```

Comment: If there is anyone who has worked with External Unifi AC need help on how to make it work